# What is the precision of the time.time() function?

Tags: python, precision

I've been playing around with the time.time() function, which prints the time elapsed since . When printing its result, I've tried multiplying it with a number on the power of 10. I've expected that I will eventually see a number with zeroes at the end (e.g. 1516895254.85 * 10000 = 15168952548500). Instead, it went as far as printing a 309-digit number, with no zeroes at the end, when reaching the function's precision.

```
>>> print('{0}'.format(int(time() * (10**299))))

151688275429037515979926334429405401106271490533817517185371446220795471128402317934144559501851174348970520458946580306822182798812776130098014987340202895198224161052094530708120342982016788576011755725325408112135784020427445752709662939740525586044947507255593760381150928852505533344315172483047700299776
```

At 310, it didn't start printing zeroes, but gave me the error message:

```
OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float
```

It seems impossible that python's time measurement would be THAT precise. Does anyone know what is happening? Are these random digits? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Edit: Thank you for your answers, sorry for asking a duplicate question.

Comment: Use `from decimal import Decimal`.

Comment: This probably varies by OS. I'm on Windows and multiplying by 10e6 seems to be sufficient to get a whole number (or something that looks like it; you never can tell with floats :-P).

Comment: Computers don't use base 10

Comment: It’s a float. So it’s already imprecise to begin with. You probably shouldn’t do anything with more than 3-6 of its decimal places.

Comment: Compare your output with the output of `int(0.1 * (10 ** 299))`.

Comment: What John Coleman said. BTW, on modern versions of Python you should use [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) for high resolution timing info.

Comment: You should probably take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken and the Wikipedia articles on floating point and IEEE-754, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: FYI: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @lehoo Welcome to [so]! It's better to leave comments as comments rather than at the bottom of the answer.